# Последний слайд равен нулю

Tags: jquery

Запилил простой слайдер, вот код:

```
$('.portfolio-slider .slide-button').on('click',function(){
    var buttonPrev = $(this).hasClass('slide-prev'), buttonNext = $(this).hasClass('slide-next');
    var slideBlock = $('.portfolio-slider .-slide'), slideActive = $('.portfolio-slider .-slide.slide-active');
    var slideLen = slideBlock.length, slideActiveIndex = slideActive.index();

    slideBlock.removeClass('slide-active');

    if(buttonPrev) {
        slideBlock.eq(slideActiveIndex-1).addClass('slide-active');
        console.info('slide: '+(slideActiveIndex-1)+'/'+slideLen);
    }
    if(buttonNext) {
        slideBlock.eq(slideActiveIndex+1).addClass('slide-active');
        console.info('slide: '+(slideActiveIndex+1)+'/'+slideLen);
    }
});
```

Проблема в том, что когда на последнем слайде нажимаешь `buttonNext`, то открывается нулевой слайд..
Да, я знаю о том что отсчёт с нуля.. Но вот где?
И как его сделать не нулевым, а первым?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам спросил - сам разобрался -_-

Добавил вот этот код в условие `if(buttonNext)`

```
var slideNext = (slideActiveIndex+1);
if(slideNext==slideLen) var slideNext = 0;
```